# Server Side PGP Encryption of String

Tags: javascript, php, encryption

So I have been researching this quite a bit, but it seems there are no ways to encrypt a message server side with PHP for use in client side javascript decryption.

I am using OpenPGPJS for the client side operations.

How do I PGP encrypt a string using just a single public key which I have generated client side with Javascript. I have already passed a variable from client side to server side so we don't have to worry about that. They all seem to ask for a fingerprint etc.

TLDR; I need to generate an encrypted pgp message using a public key that I have as a variable in php

So this is a PHP question, not a javascript question necessarily